# Не импортируется папка

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Пытаюсь импортировать папку `commands`:

```
from commands import *
```

Но встречаю проблему, что файл `TestCommand.py` не импортируется. Если импортировать папку так:

```
from commands import TestCommand
```

то файл успешно работает. Как импортировать папку `commands` импортируя ВСЕ ее содержимое?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

То, что Вы называете папкой, представляет из себя [пакет](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). Автоматического способа импортировать из пакета все модули нет. Но Вы можете сделать это вручную, [явно указав](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package), как инициализировать его.

Для этого в файл `__init__.py` добавьте переменную `__all__`, содержащую названия модулей, которые должны быть импортированы:

```py
__all__ = ['TestCommand']
```

---

Дерево каталогов:

```
│   main.py
│
└───commands
        TestCommand.py
        __init__.py
```